# Assign a static IP to a Windows Server 2008 R2 - where to get static IP addresses

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, local-area-network, static-ip

On Windows Server 2008 R2, I know how to assign a static IP address to that from lan properties windows.

In my current server, I am working with a hosting provider and they provide me 5 IP address and added them to my machine.

I also have a server at home and I would like to configure it to use a static ip address. But I am not sure where to get static IP addresses to use.

Any idea?

Comment: Please read our FAQ - this site is for professional sysadmins and this is an astonishingly basic question that has no place here.

Comment: @TomTom - what have SU done to deserve such an awful 'question' - best to kill it surely.

Comment: @Chopper3 you gotta be kidding me? I am not an IT pro and here is to place to ask questions about servers. The question might be easy for you but it doesn't mean it is not qualified and it is certainly not awful. On the other side, your manner is awful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a Windows server that is directly connected to the Internet ?

I would re-think that for a bit if I were you...

Nevertheless, if you're talking about **public** IP addresses, these are owned and given out by your ISP - talk to them on how to get more.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [rfc1918](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html) Address Allocation for Private Internets or ask your current ISP to provide you with one.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah.Ask your provider or just codeysour network to use one of the known private addresses, coordinating this with your router. if you odont know how tod do that tell - we will gladlyforward your question to the superuser.com forum, as this here is for professional admins as per FAQ.